# the first character of first name followed by first character of last name, then the second character of the first name

Tags: java, c

So i want to arrange the string = "Deepak Pundir" into an order such as "Dpeuenpdaikr" by taking the first character of first name followed by first character of last name, then the second character of the first name, then the second character of the last name, and so on.

Comment: You tagged your question with `java`, `.net` and `c`... What is the question ?

Comment: I would suggest that you sit down and "manually" scramble some names. Meaning - step by step, identify the next character, write down the current result, the indexes within the input strings ... and so on. By doing so you will soon figure how to write a program to do that task for you. This is a simple but interesting challenge; you gain much more by doing it  yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippit that shows you a basic algorithm for doing what you want:

```
String[] components = name.split(" "); // get the first and last names
if(components.length < 2) return; // check for valid string
StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
for(int x = 0;x < components[0].length && x < components[1].length;x++)
    build.append(components[0].charAt(x) + components[1].charAt(x));

String result = build.toString();
```

For C, this algorithm is very similiar. You just need to use strtok instead of split:

- [strtok](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm): get tokens from a string